# Добавить класс корзине если она не пуста

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день всем! Помогите решить проблему) Есть кусок кода

```
<a href="/cart/" class="cart">Корзина: 
<span class="cart-empty">0</span> шт.
На сумму:
0 руб.</a>
```

Код корзина пустая

```
<a href="/cart/" class="cart">Корзина: 
<span class="cart-empty">2</span> шт.
На сумму:
2000 руб.</a>
```

код корзины полная

Над если корзина не пуста, присвоить допол. класс class="cart".

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Делайте ее изначально с этим классом, потом в коде добавления товаров в корзину - меняете и класс. Я же так понимаю добавление товаров идет с помощью ajax?

Comment: да, ajax. Я думал что-то типа проверки сделать на JS. если 0 товаров в  корзине, добавление класса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
if($('.cart-empty').text() > 0)
{
 $('.cart').toggleClass('full');
}
})
```

```css
.full
{
 background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/cart/" class="cart">Корзина: 
<span class="cart-empty">2</span> шт.
На сумму:
2000 руб.</a>
```

Comment: То что надо! Спасибо большое!!! Надо учить JS)))